# Efficiently return totalrows when paging?

Tags: sql-server-2012

For paging, I usually use something like this in an sql server 2012 stored proc (using sys.system_columns, not sure if that is a good table to demonstrate):

```
DECLARE
    @page INT = 10,
    @pagesize INT = 10;

WITH syscols AS
(
    SELECT
        TotalRows = COUNT(1) OVER (),
        RowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  name),
        Name
    FROM sys.system_columns c
)
SELECT *
FROM syscols
WHERE RowNo BETWEEN 1 + (@page - 1) * @pagesize AND  @page * @pagesize
ORDER BY RowNo;
```

I hate including the TotalRows number in every row and was wondering, if there is a proper way to return the TotalRows number (e.g. OUTPUT parameter) - but without using a table variable or anything which would make the query less efficient?

Comment: Why don't you just issue a separate query, but only once?

Comment: You might want to look at the [OFFSET and FETCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) statements that were added to the ORDER BY clause with SQL Server 2012.
http://www.dbadiaries.com/new-t-sql-features-in-sql-server-2012-offset-and-fetch has a nice intro to the features.

Comment: @alzaimar: I am trying to avoid the cost of that additional query - I have not tested this thoroughly but noticed a performance gain when using COUNT(1) OVER () instead of a separate query.

Comment: @jpw: Thanks for the reminder... I actually read about this in the "new features" list but forgot all about it. A nice optimization (saves the cte) and a simpler query. Still - it would be great to cover the TotalRows in the same query.

Comment: @TvdH: You have to run through all the rows anyway to determine the total. There is no way around that (in some cases, you might use a trick, though, i.e. when there is no WHERE filter and you are querying a table)

Comment: @alzaimar: In my tests, the costs for the count(*) query and the actual query were almost the same. Therefore the additional "TotalRows" column seemed to be the smaller burden.